# Unable to access parameters from another file method

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm a beginner in the world of SwiftUI and I've a trouble while developing my first app.

I dont't know why I'm not able to access model parameters from an external swift file.

Here's the FirebaseManager file:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class FirestoreManager : ObservableObject {

    @Published var serate = [SerateModel]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {
        db.collection("Serate").addSnapshotListener{(querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No Documents")
                return
            }
        
            self.serate = documents.map{ ( queryDocumentSnapshot) -> SerateModel in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let author = data["author"] as? String ?? ""
                let image = data["image"] as? String ?? ""
                
                return SerateModel(nomeSerata: name, autoreSerata: author, immagineSerata: image)
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Here the view file which doesn't suggest the model parameters:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CategoryView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var fire = FirestoreManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators:false){
            HStack {
                cardCategoryView(image: fire.serate.image, title: fire.serate.name, author: fire.serate.author)
            }
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
        }
        .onAppear() {
            self.fire.fetchData()
        }
    }

}
```

In particular, at line 9 of this last file, it doesn't suggest me fire.serate.image but just fire.serate .

Here's also the model file:

```
struct SerateModel : Identifiable {
    var id : String = UUID().uuidString
    var nomeSerata : String
    var autoreSerata : String
    var immagineSerata : String
}
```

Thanks in advance guys.

---

### Update

I tried both the solution proposed by jnpdx and still doesn't work.

In both cases xCode is not able to suggest me the full path
**fire.serate.something**.

For example, for variable Image, the error is:

> Value of type '[SerateModel]' has no member 'image'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the `image`, `name`, and `author` properties of `SerateModel`, which doesn't have any properties of those names (at least in the same language).

One solution is to change the way you access the names (demonstrated below).

Secondly, your `serate` property is an *array* of ``, not a singular item. So, you'll have to iterate over it using something like `ForEach`.

```
HStack {
  ForEach(fire.serate, id: \.id) { serate in 
    cardCategoryView(image: serate.immagineSerata, title: serate.nomeSerata, author: serate.autoreSerata)
  }
}
```

---

Another option is keep your current `cardCategoryView` line, but rename the properties on your model:

```
struct SerateModel : Identifiable {
    var id : String = UUID().uuidString
    var name : String
    var author : String
    var image : String
}
```

And, when you create it inside `fetchData`:

```
return SerateModel(name: name, author: author, image: image)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the same issue using both methods. Any suggest?

Comment: Please update your question with what you tried. It’s impossible for it to be exactly the same issue.

Comment: @FabrizioRocco See my updated answer. You're trying to access a single element on an Array. You have to iterate through the items (or chose a singular item)